# how to run a laravel older version (8.0) project without upgrading it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I got a project, it is on laravel 8, and I have laravel 9 in my machine. I also have received its database copy. I tried so many times but i am still unable to run the project on my machine. Right now i am facint index.php file missing error.

Is this error because of older version of laravel?
How can i run this project?

Please help...
Thanks in advance.

I create a new laravel project and to make changes in the .env file as it should be for a local envirenment.
I have made changes in the database.php in config folder to make sure it matches with the database i have imported.

I haven't run the composer upgrade and the following commands.
I have a copy of the database so i didn't run the "php artisan migrate" command.

Comment: how are you trying to run it? Are you using `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: Yes, I am using php artisan serve

Comment: The version of Laravel is not on a per machine basis but is determined by your composer.json . It's likely files were missing when you were given the project. If `public/index.php` specifically is missing you can [replace it](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/public/index.php)

Comment: Warning: require_once(D:\2023\glancewebtime\timeline\system/public/index.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\2023\glancewebtime\timeline\system\server.php on line 21

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'D:\2023\glancewebtime\timeline\system/public/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\2023\glancewebtime\timeline\system\server.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\2023\glancewebtime\timeline\system\server.php on line 21

This is the error I'm facing. after doing some changes

Comment: Does the file actually exist? If you got this project from someone else they should have provided it as well

Comment: I got it... It was the issue I was facing. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqyrS0Vxr_I&ab_channel=Webappfix

Great Thanks for your time and attention. 

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to Create a new Laravel project with Laravel 8 using the composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myproject "8.*" command in the terminal.
2. Copy the files from your existing Laravel 8 project into the new project directory.
3. Update the .env file in the new project directory to match the configuration settings from your previous project.
4. Run `composer update` to install all the required packages for the new project.
5. If you have made any changes to the config/database.php file, make sure they match the database you imported.

Comment: I did all the steps you mentioned but It's still not working. This project was created by someone else.


Warning: require_once(D:\2023\glancewebtime\timeline\system/public/index.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\2023\glancewebtime\timeline\system\server.php on line 21

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'D:\2023\glancewebtime\timeline\system/public/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\2023\glancewebtime\timeline\system\server.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\2023\glancewebtime\timeline\system\server.php on line 21